# Upgrades available for Student Teacher versions of Adobe Creative Suite? CS5.5 or future?

Tags: upgrade, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

As an example, if I own Adobe CS5 Design Standard Student Teacher version, is there any way for me to upgrade to the Adobe CS5.5 Design Standard Student Teacher version?  Adobe state in their Student Teacher [FAQs](http://www.adobe.com/education/students/studentteacheredition/faq.html) that you can upgrade from a Student Teacher version to a full commercial version, but they don't address the issue of upgrading versions while remaining in the Student Teacher realm.

FYI: My example above is fictional. I actually don't own Creative Suite yet.  I'm trying to decide which CS5.5 Student Teacher package to purchase; and wanting to know what my upgrade options will be in the future, once CS moves to version 6 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sold quite a few Adobe products to people in England. I have never sold any educational products, but, I do have access to the complete product list.

I can only speak for England and whilst I can see many SKUs that list `Student`, I can't see any that say upgrade.

Along with this, I randomly checked 4 student programs, and in each case, they cost less than the regular upgrade cost.

Apart from being a student, there are no license conditions (As far as I can see), however, it is not designed for commercial purposes, The student edition is designed to learn and use features of the program. In most situations, the majority of people will be using the same version of the product throughout the entirety of their course and upgrading to a different version may be incompatible with the curriculum of the course you require it for.

(It is 6AM UK Time, if you want confirmation later in the day, let me know and I can try to ring my contact at Adobe)

Comment: Thanks William.  Your explanation along with the lack of any sign of Student-Teacher edition upgrade products online pretty much confirms it.  Although, one point of difference in the US is that the Student Teacher editions can be used for commercial purposes. See http://www.adobe.com/education/students/studentteacheredition/faq.html.  In light of that I was hoping to find that these editions were also upgradable.  Oh well.

Comment: @Matt - I checked and maybe I didn't make it clear - also here, whilst it is not a designed for commercial license, there are no conditions that prevent you from using it that way if you wish - only license conditions are you are a student when purchasing.